# jquery UI time picker styling odd

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i am using time-picker for my input.

```
<input type="text" id="stime" name='etime' placeholder='hh:mm' readonly="true"/>
```

with the script:

```
$(function() {
$('#stime').timepicker({hourMin: 8,hourMax: 10});
});
```

for this i'm using

jquery-1.10.1

jquery-ui with smoothness jquery-ui css

[jquery-ui-timepicker-addon](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) with javascript and css.

the problem is the slider for my minute is kind of overlapped on 'e' of 'minute'. looked all the css files. but unable to fix. pls help. (i've formatted according to me. with the default one also it the minute slider is same.)

[image]

Comment: Hard to say what's going on without seeing more. A demo on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com would help.

Comment: @muistooshort tried. but can't upload a javascript file or css file. and that timepicker addon doesn't provide a CDN link.

Comment: @AmirHosseinMehrvarzi what's that and how to get those details?

Answer (score 0):

The font-size for "Minute" is set to a relative value of 85%. It appears you have an ancestor element that is applying a larger than expected font size, and your text is enlarged and bleeding into the slider. Either fiddle with that ancestor's font-size (the body element, maybe?), or override the label:

```
.ui_tpicker_minute_label{ font-size:65%; }
```

Comment: tried that many times. doesn't work. just to be sure i created another page with that much html only without any other css styling except jquery ui and timepicker-addon. but same. no profit.

Comment: Can you apply !important to your style rule?